# mysqlimport, can it import CSV data concurrently from separate nodes

Tags: mysql, bash, mysqlimport

I need to build a process that imports csv data to a single table on my mysql database. The process needs to run independently on each individual server. Can I execute this statement on multiple separate servers, concurrently?

```
 mysqlimport  --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=,
 --columns='ID,Name,Phone,Address' --local -u root -p xxx
 Database /path/to/csvfile/TableName.csv
```

Comment: you didn't provide any password for accessing the server, I hope you paid attention to that

Comment: Wrong syntax with option `-p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is happy to receive data from multiple connections "simultaneously", even into a single table.

If you have duplicate `UNIQUE` keys, then there could be errors that you would be ignoring, so be cautious.